# Optimizacion arranque aplicacion net core 3 en desarrollo

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Trabajo en un proyecto MVC con net core 3 y EF 3. Son 112 proyectos por ahora , con uno principal y multiples proyectos en dependencia. El caso es que para depurar se demora el arranque como 7 minutos, usamos para el desarrollo Visual Studio 2022.
¿Se puede analizar o depurar los bloqueos en el arranque con net core?

Comment: 112! proyectos.. y si.. va a tardar.. en serio se necesitan tantos proyectos encadenados en una sola solucion??? cada vez que le das play, obviamente, compila todos!!!! Porque esta estructurado de esa forma??? tan grande es el equipo y el proyecto?? no se pueden hacer librerias que no tengas que compilar cada vez?